# AutoLayout - UIImageView that doesn't rotate

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout

How can I get a `UIImageView` to not rotate when the user rotates their phone?

All other views in the view controller should update with auto-layout as normal, but I want the `UIImageView` to stay constant.

How can I accomplish this? Right now I'm rotating the image in `viewWillTransitionToSize`, but that looks terrible and doesn't account for `LandscapeLeft` vs. `LandscapeRight`

Answer (score -1):

There's no magic flag to have a UIView not rotate, but you could rotate it back with the following code:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Request to turn on accelerometer and begin receiving accelerometer events
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Respond to changes in device orientation
    switch ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            self.img.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            self.img.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            self.img.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            self.img.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp:
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown:
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationUnknown:
            break;
    }
}

-(void) viewDidDisappear {
    // Request to stop receiving accelerometer events and turn off accelerometer
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
}
```

Comment: This does not preserve the exact size of the image, and it appears to rotate during rotation as well, which is incredibly sloppy.